# WebEclipse Javascript debugger not installed error in eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, debugging, protractor

I have installed Tern debugger when i try to re-install it then it showing me message - "Debugger Support for Webclipse" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

But when i try to debug my protractor test in Eclipse Juno IDE then it showing error- WebEclipse Javascript debugger not installed. Can Anybody help me where i missed??

Comment: Have you installed WebEclipse ?

Comment: I am working with Eclipse Luna

Comment: You need to install Webclipse https://www.genuitec.com/products/webclipse/ if you wish to debug with Webclipse

Comment: I want to debug protractor script through eclipse luna. Its written in your repository that for that you require tern debugger https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/wiki/Protractor
i have installed tern debugger but when i try to debug from eclipse luna i am getting this error that no webclipse js debugger installed.

Comment: You miss to read https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Debugging-Tern.js-on-Node.js Now Eclipse Neon provides debugging support, I'm planning to add it to the tern debugger.